# Rendering fetched data from api is affecting scss layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I've written a React component that fetches some data from my api, which works as expected, but the issue is how it's being rendered. I have an scss file that contains a simple grid that helps lay out my data into columns and this is the result [rendering data from useEffect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkHwV.png). As you can see the layout is all over the place but the data is being displayed. However, if I create a hard copy of the data to represent what's being fetched from the api I get what should be happening [rendering data from hard coded array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guRKX.png). The data set/structure is exactly the same so I'm not sure what's going on and why it's behaving differently with the fetched data.

```
const Projects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/projects')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setProjects(res));
  }, []);
  
  return (
    projects.map(({ id, name, description, language, html_url }) => (
      <div key={id} className='col-4'>
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        <p>{description}</p>
        <p>{language}</p>
        <a href={html_url}>See project</a>
      </div>
    ))
  )
};
```

Comment: please post your scss code it doesn't seem like a react issue but just some styling that broke depending on data.

Comment: Hey Antoine, I'm using https://simplegrid.io/ for my layout. I thought this was an issue at first so I used my own scss grid and had the exact same problem.